# extracting lines from a large text file

Tags: grep

I have a text file with data that looks like this (1875 lines to be exact)

```
chr1    MOTEVOC_cage_181208 TF_binding_site_cage_181208 6585538 6585547 0.905022147 -   .   TF_binding_site_cage_181208 MEF2A,B,C,D-148428 ;ALIAS MEF2A,MEF2B,MEF2C,MEF2D ;L3_ID L3_chr1_-_6585517 
chr1    MOTEVOC_cage_181208 TF_binding_site_cage_181208 6767855 6767864 0.703029237 +   .   TF_binding_site_cage_181208 MEF2A,B,C,D-148303 ;ALIAS MEF2A,MEF2B,MEF2C,MEF2D ;L3_ID L3_chr1_+_6768100 
chr1    MOTEVOC_cage_181208 TF_binding_site_cage_181208 8686283 8686292 0.481284243 +   .   TF_binding_site_cage_181208 MEF2A,B,C,D-148085 ;ALIAS MEF2A,MEF2B,MEF2C,MEF2D ;L3_ID L3_chr1_-_8685906 
chr1    MOTEVOC_cage_181208 TF_binding_site_cage_181208 10660924    10660933    0.818294903 +   .   TF_binding_site_cage_181208 MEF2A,B,C,D-148400 ;ALIAS MEF2A,MEF2B,MEF2C,MEF2D ;L3_ID L3_chr1_+_10661128 
chr1    MOTEVOC_cage_181208 TF_binding_site_cage_181208 12327417    12327426    0.584010382 -   .   TF_binding_site_cage_181208 MEF2A,B,C,D-148387 ;ALIAS MEF2A,MEF2B,MEF2C,MEF2D ;L3_ID L3_chr1_+_12327504 
chr1    MOTEVOC_cage_181208 TF_binding_site_cage_181208 12327433    12327442    0.825226087 -   .   TF_binding_site_cage_181208 MEF2A,B,C,D-148388 ;ALIAS MEF2A,MEF2B,MEF2C,MEF2D ;L3_ID L3_chr1_+_12327504
```

I am looking for a solution to extract the lines that have "+" near the very end. (it happens after the last `;`. Similarly, I am looking to extract the `-` strand lines and put in a separate files.

Edit: change of data set, was looking at the wrong file before.

Comment: Is that the unique format of the file?

Comment: Yes. John's answer below did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments, I understand that you are looking to extract lines whose 7th column is either `+` or `-`.  The input file is tab-separated.  To do that, while saving the `+` lines to the file called `plus` and the minus lines to the file called `minus`, the most natural tool is probably `awk`:

```
awk -F'\t' '$7=="+"{print >"plus"} $7=="-"{print>"minus"}' file
```

How it works:

- `-F'\t'`

  `awk` reads in a record (line) at a time and separates it into fields.  Here, we set the field-separator to a tab.
- `$7=="+"{print >"plus"}`

  If the 7th field is a `+`, then save the line in the file `plus`.
- `$7=="-"{print>"minus"}`

  Similarly, if the 7th field is a `-`, then save the line in the file `minus`.

Comment: I've actually edited my dataset. The plus/minus at the end is NOT the one I am looking for. I am looking for the one in the middle (they don't have to be the same)

Comment: The lines are tab delimited. I am looking for the 7th column (index starting at 1). So `chr1 | MOTEVOC_cage_181208 | TF_binding_site_cage_181208 | 6585538 | 6585547 | 0.905022147 | - | . |  TF_binding_site_cage_181208 MEF2A, ...(so on)`

Comment: Ah thanks for the explanation! At first I thought it wasn't doing anything, would just return to the console, but from your explanations, it is writing to those files.

Comment: Funny thing. The tool I am using to process the plus/minus files can already detect "strand" (+/-) information from the original file. Oh well, atleast I learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ne '/^[^+-]*+/w plus.file' -e //d -e '/^[^+-]-/w minus.file' <infile
```

For the seventh tab-delimited section do:

```
sed -ne 'h;s/\([^\t]*\t\)\{6\}[^\t+-]*//
            /^-/{g;w minus.file' -e 'b
         }; /^+/{g;w plus.file'  -e \}
```

But you may have to use a literal `<tab>` character in place of the `\t` escapes above.

Comment: Thanks. I've gone ahead with John's solution for now. I understood it better :P